# replace string after x number of characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to remove string after x number of text. then replace with some dots "..." like this. I already tried the code below but not works. I think I am able to describe problem if you still have problem then please ask in comments section

getting error:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'No overload
>   for method 'Replace' takes '1' arguments'

Any idea how to do this?

```
string s = "i am a cow"; 
string w = s.Remove(4).Replace("...");
```

I want output as: I am...

Comment: This is what you need: `string w = s.Remove(4).Replace("string_to_replace", "...");`

Comment: "replacement_string" mean?

Comment: `String.Replace` requires at least 2 arguments: string to replace with & replacement string.

Comment: I think you should use this based from desired output: `w = s.Remove(s.Length - n, n) + "..."` (n = characters to remove) or simpler `w = s.Substring(0, 4) + "..."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try with following syntax.

```
string s= "i am a cow";
        var st = s.Substring(4, 6);
        string w =s.Replace(st,"...");
```